# Navigate to specific screen when clicked on notification?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-fcm

I am using react-native-fcm for notification and successfully receiving notification. My problem is when i click on that notification it must navigate to specific screen.

I have a stack navigator with home and alerts.
i am writing my code in login which much navigate to alerts.

```
FCM.on(FCMEvent.Notification, async (notif) => {
if (notificationData.message === 'New alert generated.') {

        FCM.presentLocalNotification({
            vibrate: 500,
            title: 'title',
            priority: "high",
            show_in_foreground: true,
            group: 'test',
            large_icon: "ic_launcher",
            icon: "ic_launcher",
        });
    }
}
```

Here im using presentLocalNotification() to show notification. where should i use `this.props.navigation.navigate('alerts');`

Answer (score -1):

```
FCM.on(FCMEvent.Notification, async (notif) => {
 if(notif){
  if(notif.opened_from_tray && notif.local_notification) {
     // Handle navigation here
     this.props.navigation.navigate('alerts');
   } else {
     FCM.presentLocalNotification({
            vibrate: 500,
            title: 'title',
            priority: "high",
            show_in_foreground: true,
            group: 'test',
            large_icon: "ic_launcher",
            icon: "ic_launcher",
        });
   }
 }
}
```